# C++ and Assembly: call 'operator new' and 'operator delete' with ASM

Tags: c++, assembly, new-operator, inline-assembly, delete-operator

I am trying to call `operator new` and `operator delete` with inline ASM in Visual C++.

For example, I have a function like this:

```
__forceinline void __fastcall deallocate(pointer& _ptr)
{
    __asm
    {
        mov eax, dword ptr[_ptr]
        mov ecx, dword ptr[eax]
        mov dword ptr[eax], 0
        push ecx
        call operator delete
        add esp, 4
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, when compiling, I get these errors:

```
error C2414: illegal number of operands
error C2400: inline assembler syntax error in 'first operand'; found 'bad token'
error C2400: inline assembler syntax error in 'opcode'; found 'bad token'
```

I know this has to do with calling `operator delete.` If I replace it with a function like this:

```
__forceinline void _delete(pointer _ptr)
{
    ::operator delete(_ptr);
}
```

and write

```
call _delete
```

in the ASM code section, I get no errors. Can anybody tell me why and what should I do? I don't want to use this `_delete` function. This also happens if I try calling `operator new` in a similar manner. Thank you.

Comment: One problem with your approach is that there is a different operator delete for each type, how would the assembler know which one you want?

Comment: Do you think there is any way of solving this?

Comment: I'm trying to think of a reason why you would want to break out of C++ to Assembly to do this...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this call is ambiguous. Each type can define its own `operator new` and `operator delete`. How ASM would know which one it should call?

Also, I think, that token with spaces is not a valid name in ASM (or even C). C++ compilers were designed to differently treat `operator` keyword, as the name of operator is often separated with white space. I don't think ASM knows anything about this.

That's why you are getting this error:

`error C2414: illegal number of operands`

In ASM we separate operands with white spaces. Since you tried to call `operator delete`, ASM interpreted this as two operands, which is too many for `call` instruction.

Comment: I also thought about 'operator' as being a keyword that is not recognized by ASM. Do you think there is any way of solving this problem?

Comment: ASM doesn't know anything about templates or overloading, so I don't think it can be done this way. Note, that even assembly emitted by compilers always contains direct memory addresses for called functions. Beside that, writing assembly code for task like this is not a good idea. Also, since you use VC++, remember, that using inline assembly, makes your code very non-portable - you won't be able to compile even a native 64-bit version of your app, because on that target, inline assembly is forbidden.